# ANSI C programming by K&R getline: --lim > 0 or lim-->0?

Tags: c

On page 69 from ANSI C programming by K&R there is an example of a function that works as a special version of Unix program grep.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 //max input length
int getline(char line[], int max); 
int Strindex(char source[], char searchfor[]); 
char pattern[] = "ould"; 

int main()
{ 
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found =0;

    while (getline(line,MAXLINE) > 0)
        if (Strindex(line, pattern)>=0){
        printf("%s", line); 
        found ++; 
        }
    return found;
} // end of main function


int  getline (char s[], int lim) 
{ 
    int c, i; 
    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}


int Strindex (char s[], char t[])
{ 

    int i,j,k; 
    for (i =0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        for (i =i, k=0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++); 
    if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
        return i;

}
return -1; 

} // end of strindex
```

Isn't it an error: `--lim > 0`? If `MAXLINE` in my case will be `1`, I'll got on beginning of `while 0>0` - False and I would not get any string?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that `MAXLINE` would be 1?

Comment: there is  this code block: if (c =='\n')
        s[i++] =c;  which would overrun the input buffer if the test of 'lim' were changed.

Comment: And the behaviour of reading nothing would be correct, because a 1-character buffer can only hold the null terminator for the string and not any data.  Note that this exercise has been caught (overtaken) by the POSIX standard; there is now a standard function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which has a wholly different interface to this `getline()`.

Comment: Note that there are bugs in `Strindex()`.  Notably, there's a `return -1;` and a `}` after the end of the function (the earlier `}` is probably the interloper, or you missed an `{` after the first `for` loop.  The second loop has its `;` empty statement on the same line as the loop control; that's not the way K&R tell you to write a loop with an empty statement as the loop body.  The `for (i = i, k = 0; …` part is dubious; you never set `j` to a value, but you increment it, so it should be `for (j = i, k = 0; …`. The spacing around binary operators such as `=` should be symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right and wrong. You would get an empty NUL terminated string (`lim` is supposed to include the terminating NUL character). A valid C-string should be NUL terminated and even a zero length string contains at least one character. So, if your MAXLINE is 1, it's already full and can't hold any more characters.

```
while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n')
    s[i++] =c; 
if (c =='\n')
    s[i++] =c; 
s[i] = '\0' ;
```

The last statement `s[i] = '\0'` is assigning the NUL character, which in your case would be `s[0] = '\0';`. Also, the getline function is correctly returning the length of captured string (=0) in the next statement `return i;`.

Comment: Be careful: NULL is a null pointer constant, and not the null byte or `'\0'`. Also note that the length of a string does not include the null terminator (the standard is quite clear on that: _A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character. … The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I edited about the NULLs. But I think I'm right on stringlength.